# Portuguese accents not working on PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Recently on a fresh Ubuntu installation, suddenly PHPStorm stopped allowing me to use words with portuguese accents.

For example:

```
Trying TILDE+A should result in: ã
Instead it results in: a
```

And this happens with other accents like:

```
Trying DIACRITICAL SIGN+E should result in: é
Instead it results in: e
```

Currently the laptop configuration is as follows:

- OS: Ubuntu 15.04
- Java: OpenJDK 8 (OpenJDK 7 did not worked also)
- PHPStorm 8.0.3
- Keyboard: Portuguese

Note 1: I think the problem may be related with key bindings once that the standalone key c-cedilla works just fine.

Note 2: My mother language isn't English so errors may occur, feel free to correct me. I appreciate it.

Any further help would be appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, so after some days struggling against this problem I finally found out what I already expected since the beginning, this is a problem related to java itself.

In order for special characters to work we've to clean up the XMODIFIERS environment variable, like so:

```
# Command to change the environment variable XMODIFIERS
export XMODIFIERS=""
# PhpStorm run, for testing if it worked
pstorm
```

And for me it did work!

So, after testing I just added the export command to my ~/.bashrc file so this change takes effect every time and not only that one when we've changed it manually in a terminal window. In the end of your .bashrc file paste the following (same command as above):

```
export XMODIFIERS=""
```

I got the tip from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/581769/410364

Comment: something might have changed, because this workaround does not work for me. I'm on Arch btw

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, add the `export XMODIFIERS=""` on rc file didn't work (put it on .bashrc and in the .zshrc). Even put in .profile file doesn't work. So, I create a shell file with:

```
export XMODIFIERS=""

/opt/PhpStorm-191.6183.95/bin/phpstorm.sh
```

and put that shell file in the PHPStorm .desktop file as a program filepath. It's work to me :)

Answer (score 0):

To me works with this:

```
export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1
ibus-daemon -d -r
```